# If two elements in a ED have the same Euclidean norm, are they associates?

Tags: ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, euclidean-algorithm

> Is it obvious that in a Euclidean Domain two elements $x$ and $y$ having the same Euclidean norm are associates?

Can someone give me a proof of this?

Comment: Might it be possible to give a characterization of all Euclidean domains (which are not fields) for which equality of norms implies elements are associates?  Assuming the norm is multiplicative (as I like to...), this implies an injection of monoids $(R \setminus \{0\})/R^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$, which seems quite restrictive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Consider the Euclidean domain $\mathbb R[x]$, which has Euclidean norm $\nu(f)=\mathrm{deg}(f)$. Then for example $x^2+1$ and $x^2+x+1$ have the same norm but are not associates, as the units are nonzero elements of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ah ok, so I guess that's only true in the Gaussian integers?

Comment: @morphism, not even there. See my answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's odd because my lecture notes use this when proving: ''If $x \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\nu (x)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ then $x$ is Gaussian prime.'' And we have that if $\nu (x) = p$ and if $\nu(y) | \nu(x)$  then $\nu (y)$ is $1$ or $p$, and if $\nu(y) = p$, 'then $x$ is associate to $y$'...

Comment: @morphism Just because it holds for primes doesn't mean it holds for all natural numbers. But the statement "If $x\in \mathbb Z[i]$ and $\nu(x)$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$ then $x$ is Gaussian prime.'' is actually false, for example, $5$ is not a Gaussian prime.

Comment: @AlexBecker, $N(5)=25$.

Comment: @lhf Ah, I was thinking the unsquared version.

Comment: So is it true?..

Comment: @morphism Wikipedia says yes.

Comment: @morphism and it is easy to prove: $x$ not prime implies $x=ab$ implies $N(x)=N(a)N(b)$ not prime. You need to know that $N(u)=1$ iff $u$ is a unit.

Comment: @lhf Of course, that only works if you already know $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a UFD (so that all nonprimes are not irreducible).

Answer (score 5):

In $\mathbb Z[i]$, we have $N(1+7i)=50=N(5+5i)$ but $1+7i$ and $5+5i$ are not associates.

Comment: A simpler counterexample is $1 + 2i, 1 - 2i$.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not true, what you seem to want *is* true (based on the comments): an element $x$ of a Euclidean domain is a unit if and only if $\nu(x)=\nu(1)$.

To see this, note that $\nu(1)\leq\nu(z)$ for all $z\neq 0$ (since $\nu(1)\leq\nu(1z)$). If $x$ is a unit, then $\nu(x)\leq\nu(xx^{-1})=\nu(1)$ gives the equality.

Conversely, if $\nu(x)=\nu(1)$, divide $1$ by $x$ to get $1 = xy+r$ with $r=0$ or $\nu(r)\lt(x)=\nu(1)$. But $r\neq 0$ implies $\nu(r)\geq \nu(1)$, so we conclude that $r=0$ so $x$ is a unit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ If it were true, then in a norm-euclidean quadratic field, *ramification* would be rampant

$$\rm\:N(w) = ww' = N(w')\:\Rightarrow\:(w) = (w')\:\Rightarrow\:(p) = (p,w)(p,w') = (p,w)^2 $$